# How to use SGD for time series analysis

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing, time-series, classification, regression

Is it possible to use [stochastic gradient descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) for time-series analysis?

My initial idea, given a series of (t, v) pairs where I want an SGD regressor to predict the v associated with t+1, would be to convert the date/time into an integer value, and train the regressor on this list using the hinge loss function. Is this feasible?

Edit: This is example code using the [SGD implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html) in scikit-learn. However, it fails to properly predict a simple linear time series model. All it seems to do is calculate the average of the training Y-values, and use that as its prediction of the test Y-values. Is SGD just unsuitable for time-series-analysis or am I formulating this incorrectly?

```
from datetime import date
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

# Build data.
s = date(2010,1,1)
i = 0
training = []
for _ in xrange(12):
    i += 1
    training.append([[date(2012,1,i).toordinal()], i])
testing = []
for _ in xrange(12):
    i += 1
    testing.append([[date(2012,1,i).toordinal()], i])

clf = SGDRegressor(loss='huber')

print 'Training...'
for _ in xrange(20):
    try:
        print _
        clf.partial_fit(X=[X for X,_ in training], y=[y for _,y in training])
    except ValueError:
        break

print 'Testing...'
for X,y in testing:
    p = clf.predict(X)
    print y,p,abs(p-y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SGDRegressor in sklearn is numerically not stable for not scaled input parameters. For good result it's highly recommended that you scale the input variable.

```py
from datetime import date
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

# Build data.
s = date(2010,1,1).toordinal()
i = 0
training = []
for _ in range(1,13):
    i += 1
    training.append([[s+i], i])
testing = []
for _ in range(13,25):
    i += 1
    testing.append([[s+i], i])

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform([X for X,_ in training])
```

after training the SGD regressor, you will have to scale the test input variable accordingly.

```py
clf = SGDRegressor()
clf.fit(X=X_train, y=[y for _,y in training])
        
print(clf.intercept_, clf.coef_)

print('Testing...')
for X,y in testing:
    p = clf.predict(scaler.transform([X]))
    print(X[0],y,p[0],abs(p[0]-y))
```

Here is the result:

```
[6.31706122] [3.35332573]
Testing...
733786 13 12.631164799851827 0.3688352001481725
733787 14 13.602565350686039 0.39743464931396133
733788 15 14.573965901520248 0.42603409847975193
733789 16 15.545366452354457 0.45463354764554254
733790 17 16.51676700318867 0.48323299681133136
733791 18 17.488167554022876 0.5118324459771237
733792 19 18.459568104857084 0.5404318951429161
733793 20 19.430968655691295 0.569031344308705
733794 21 20.402369206525506 0.5976307934744938
733795 22 21.373769757359714 0.6262302426402861
733796 23 22.34517030819392 0.6548296918060785
733797 24 23.316570859028133 0.6834291409718674
```

Answer (score 0):

The method of choice for time series prediction depends on what you know about your time series. If you choose a specific method for your task you always make implicit assumptions about the nature of your signal and the kind of system that generated the signal. Any method is always a model of the system. The more you know a priori about your signal and the system the better you are able to model it.

If your signal for instance is of stochastic nature, usually ARMA processes or Kalman filters are a good choice. If those fail, other more deterministic models might help, given, of corse, you have some information about you system.